# Left outer join , Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, linq-to-objects

I am trying to perform left outer join on 2 objects and getting an error : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

The objects look like that

```
  var deliverables = OCHART.GetACAPValues(organization, ReportingPeriod, FiscalYear, "(09-10.10a) Outreach Significant").ToList();
  var references = (from rf in OCHART.References where rf.RefType.Equals("09-10.10a") && rf.Comments.Equals("2") select rf).ToList();
```

In which deliverables might often return 0 records. Unfortunately I cannot just go and join two tables from database so deliverables must be an object.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction

Thanks,

My code is

```
 var items = (from rf in references
              join pt in deliverables on rf.Description equals pt.b into prt
              from x in prt.Where(prt2 => prt2.a.Equals(audience)).DefaultIfEmpty()
              where rf.RefType.Equals("09-10.10a") && rf.Comments.Equals("2")
              select new 
              {
                    audience = (string)(audience == null ? "" : audience),
                    RefType = (string)(rf.RefType == null ? "" : rf.RefType),
                    RefOrder = (int)(rf.RefOrder == null ? 0 : rf.RefOrder),
                    refName = (string)(rf.Description == null ? "" : rf.Description),
                    column_attr = (string)(x.b == null ? string.Empty : x.b),
                    value = (int)(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)
               })
               .OrderBy(o => o.RefOrder)
               .Take(9)
               .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

After some more debugging it appears that I get error on following lines in my code

```
column_attr = (string)(x.b == null ? string.Empty : x.b),
value = (int)(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)
```

I noticed even when I have values (added for testing) in deliverables and when values are matching the query will execute properly, but when there is no match in deliverable that's when I get the error message.

The issue is probably with handling the null values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `x` is null and is causing a `NullReferenceException` in the following lines:

```
column_attr = (string)(x.b == null ? string.Empty : x.b),
value = (int)(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)
```

This judgment is based on the `from x in` line's `DefaultIfEmpty()` call, typical of left-outer-joins.

In database code, you would write something like `x.ACAP == null` to detect the case where there was no matching join element. If you change this replace the 'x.property == null' checks with "x == null" checks, I suspect your problem will clear up.

There's still the problem with the second line - you're going to get an exception at run-time if you try to cast the value `(int?)null` to an integer. Using a meaningful default `int` value such as 0 in the case that `x == null` will clear that up.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and you spot on, I did value = (int)(x == null ? 0 : x.ACAP) and everything is working properly now. Really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you step through your code, before the query is executed do you actually see "deliverables" and "references" being populated with data ?

Investigate all child tables/properties you're using in your query. The reason you're getting that error is most likely because one of the properties you're using while comparing is null.
.RefType .Comment for example.
Maybe .RefType is null and it's having problems sorting at the end. Difficult to say without seeing what's in those two collections.

Added after your comment:

Note that it's better not to use .Equals() when your variable could be null. Use == instead. Reference: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals

Also imagine that `(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)` returns a `null`. 
You're casting that whole thing as an int : `value = (int)(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)`. Casting `null` as n `int` will obviously fail

Comment: The references are always being populated, but the deliverables list has a chance of being 0 and is empty without any records, when I debug code the error i get is on collumn_attr = (string)(x.b == null ? string.Empty : x.b) line, and on line value = (int)(x.ACAP == null ? (int?)null : x.ACAP)

Comment: I noticed even when I have values (added for testing) in deliverables and when values are matching the query will execute properly, but when there is no match that's when I get the error message. The issue is probably with handling the null values.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the new Null-conditional operators in C# 6.0 could be used like this:

```
column_attr = x?.b ?? string.Empty,
value = x?.ACAP
```